# Mysql search query for online shop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I think than search is one of most trivial problems in mysql, but i have an interesting request for online shop. By the way, I use Laravel v8 Eloquent for quering, if it helps with solution.

Lets assume that we have db table `goods`

```
id | name 
1  | Fried chicken leg
2  | Chicken freezed
3  | Vegetable soup with chicks
4  | Enchickened grains
```

and when user type `chicken` I want to show first a lines that starts with search query (id 2 in example table), and it would be perfect if after those entries were those that have a search query as entire word (id 1) that starts with it, followed by any other line that contains search query. I ask about it primarily because of need of pagination since shop has a thousands of entries, so I do not want to make and merge results for few subsequent requests

I tried to make two requests and merge them, making a pagination out of these results, but I have quite complicated and rather expensive resulting request that touches a few relations for goods like promo, categories, blocks and few more, so it will be a twice or more as expensive and this is not something I want to see if there is a way to optimize a request.

EDIT Example:
If I enter `chicken` I want to see `Chicken freezed` first, then (ideally but not required) `Fried chicken leg` and after that anything that have `chicken` in it. if prioritize in regex: `$chicken.*` -> `.*\bchicken.*` -> `%chicken%` (last one for mysql)

Comment: Your problem needs to be more specific, supply traces and query explanations of your current situation, else it’s just going to be `jQuery might solve the problem` answers ..

Comment: Do you plan to return the row with id=3 as well for the keyword search for chicken? If so, you need a lot more than just a simple query as no query can tell that chicks and chicken mean the same thing!

Comment: The `REGEXP` operator returns 0 or 1, depending on whether the given value matches the expression, or not. So you should be able to use multiple such comparisons/matches in your ORDER BY clause - `ORDER BY name REGEXP XXX, name REGEXP YYY, ...` - with `XXX` being your regular expression that matches when the word comes at the start of name, `YYY` being one that matches when the full word is contained, etc.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, this is what I wanted. I have to prevent sql-injections tho